# Draw line between rectangle from border to border

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would like to draw a line to connect two rectangle from border to border and pass through both rectangle center. currently, I can draw the line from center to center. I know if I fill the rectangle with white, then the line connection will looks like from border to border. but I do wish to keep rectangle transparent!

What's proper way to implement it?

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
.attr('width',800)
.attr('height',600)
.style('border','1px solid red')
.style('background-color','#e0e0e0')

 svg.append("defs")
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id","pointer")
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 10)
    .attr("orient","auto")
    .attr("refY", 5)
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")
    

var data = [
  {
    id:0,
    x:100,
    y:100,
    width:100,
    height:50,
  },{
    id:1,
    x:200,
    y:200,
    width:100,
    height:50,
  }
]

var links = [
  {
    src:0,
    dest:1,
  }
]

svg.selectAll(null)
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', d => d.x - d.width/2)
.attr('y', d => d.y - d.height/2)
.attr('width',d => d.width)
.attr('height', d => d.height)
.attr('fill','none')
.attr('stroke','black')
.attr('stroke-width',2)

svg.selectAll(null)
.data(links)
.enter()
.append('line')
.attr('x1',d => data.find(e => e.id === d.src).x)
.attr('y1',d => data.find(e => e.id === d.src).y)
.attr('x2',d => data.find(e => e.id === d.dest).x)
.attr('y2',d => data.find(e => e.id === d.dest).y)
.attr('stroke','black')
.attr("marker-end","url(#pointer)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You get the slope of the line from the eons-old "rise over run" equation. You also know the size of the rectangles and the location of their centers. The amount by which the center is 'buried' controls how much of the line you need to move along to arrive at the rectangle border, If the rect is 2 units wide, you'll need to move *up-to* 1 unit in the X direction. So, 1 times the rise over run constant tells you how much to modify the Y coordinate by. Think about a 45 deg line from the center of a square... Each coord changes by as much as the other. Rects just change one faster than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `linkPath` function:

```js
const first = {x: 50, y: 50, width: 40, height: 30};
const second = {x: 200, y: 110, width: 70, height: 40};
const third = {x: 80, y: 120, width: 50, height: 20};

const linkPath = (from, to) => {
  const dx = to.x - from.x;
  const dy = to.y - from.y;
  let fX, fY, tX, tY;
  const factor = dx > 0 ^ dy > 0;
  
  if (from.width / from.height > Math.abs(dx / dy)) {
    fX = from.x + from.height * dx / dy / 2 * (factor ? -1 : 1);
    fY = from.y + from.height / 2 * (factor ? -1: 1);
  }
  else {
    fX = from.x + from.width / 2 * (factor ? -1 : 1);
    fY = from.y + from.width * dy / dx / 2 * (factor ? -1 : 1);
  }

  if (to.width / to.height > Math.abs(dx / dy)) {
    tX = to.x + to.height * dx / dy / 2 * (factor ? 1 : -1);
    tY = to.y + to.height / 2 * (factor ? 1 : -1);
  }
  else {
    tX = to.x + to.width / 2 * (factor ? 1 : -1);
    tY = to.y + to.width * dy / dx / 2 * (factor ? 1 : -1);
  }

  return {from: {x: fX, y: fY}, to: {x: tX, y: tY}};  
};


const svg = d3.select('svg');

const drawRectangle = rect => 
  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('x', rect.x - rect.width / 2) 
    .attr('y', rect.y - rect.height / 2) 
    .attr('width', rect.width) 
    .attr('height', rect.height);
    
const drawLink = (from, to) => {
    const path = linkPath(from, to);
  svg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', path.from.x)
    .attr('y1', path.from.y)
    .attr('x2', path.to.x)
    .attr('y2', path.to.y)
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')
} 
    
    
drawRectangle(first);
drawRectangle(second);
drawRectangle(third);
drawLink(first, second);
drawLink(first, third);
drawLink(second, third);
```

```css
rect {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" 
    refX="10" refY="3.5" orient="auto">
      <polygon fill="black" points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```